# How to set the ant property "output.root" in shell?

Tags: shell, ant, cygwin

I need to specify the ant property `output.root` from the Cygwin shell, as I'm unable to edit the `build.xml`.  Currently, I am trying to export an environment variable, like

> export output.root="/d/output".

But that gives me an error:

> export: `output.root=/d/output': not a valid identifier

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to set Java properties from the command line, by any chance?

Comment: this property is used by ant. and I can't edit build.xml file. thats why I need to set up it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove `.` from the variable name or replace it with `_`.

**Update**

Ant properties are not shell variables. You must specify ant properties in the command line of `ant` using `-D`:

```
ant -Doutput.root="/d/output" target1
```

Comment: THis prorerty is used by ant. I can't change its name

Answer (score 0):

Only ASCII alphanumeric characters and the underscore are allowed in identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

To set ant properties from the command line, you should use the syntax

```
ant -D<property>=<value> [target [target2 [target3] ...]]
```

Reference: The [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options).